# Obtener valor de una funcion Javascript en una varible C# mvc5

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

necesito almacenar lo que me retorna una funcion JavaScript dentro de una variable en una vista C# con razor en mvc 5.

Por ejemplo lo que devuelve esta funcion:

```
    function fechafin(){
    var ff = document.getElementById("ffin").value;
    return ff;
}
```

Almacernarlo en una variable de la vista tipo:

```
@{var variableLocal = *el valor que retorna la funcion*
```

Alguna idea? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Estás confundiendo totalmente como funciona JavaScript y Razor. Primero se "ejecuta" Razor en el servidor para generar la vista (HTML y JavaScript). Luego esta vista es entregada al navegador y se ejecuta el JavaScript que puede contener esta vista. Si quieres obtener un valor en JavaScript y luego enviárselo al servidor deberá ser por una petición AJAX, armando el valor en una URL a la cual te vas a redirigir o enviándolo por POST a través de un input.

Comment: Porque relanzar una pregunta ambigua que deberia ser eliminada?

Answer (score 0):

Razor es un motor de renderizado de páginas en el sentido de que Razor **pre-procesa** el html de un archivo *cshtml* o *vbhtml* para entregarlo al cliente. Esto quiere decir que Razor "arma" el HTML que se entregará al navegador. No tiene nada que ver con JavaScript (aunque en el HTML que genera *puede* y de hecho *suele* enviar líneas de JS).

Por otro lado, JavaScript no se ejecuta en el servidor (para el caso) sino en el cliente cuando éste lo recibe. Todo lo que sucede en Javascript se queda en el cliente. A menos que...

### Peticiones asíncronas

La forma *tradicional* de mandar datos desde el cliente al servidor es a través de formularios `<form>`. Sin embargo, desde hace años **Ajax** nos ofrece una alternativa.
Con un `<form>` tienes que desencadenar el evento `send` con un botón `<button type="submit">` y al momento de hacerlo, los datos viajan a una *dirección* que los procesa y devuelve una nueva página (o sea, envías y tienes que esperar a que se descargue una nueva página completa).

Con **Ajax** ya no es necesario, sino que puedes programar peticiones al servidor (con o sin datos, como si fuera un formulario) en cualquier momento y sin tener que esperar a que se descargue toda una nueva página, sino solo un fragmento de información. Esta información puede viajar en formato XML (un documento con `<tags>` definidas por ti) o en JSON (una "cadena" de texto con una estructura de `clave:valor`) que son los formatos de intercambio de información.

Para lograr lo que tú quieres, lo que necesitas es hacer peticiones de este tipo. Te dejo un poco de literatura al respecto:

- [JSON](https://json.org)
- [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) (puedes cambiar el idioma del sitio)
- [AXIOS](https://github.com/axios/axios) (útil framework para hacer peticiones AJAX de forma fácil).
- [Formularios con MVC](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-Form-Submit-Post-example.aspx)
- [Pasar datos de JavaScript al servidor vía AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829340/how-to-pass-a-javascript-object-to-a-c-sharp-mvc-4-controller) (SO en inglés)
- [¿Qué es una API?](https://hipertextual.com/archivo/2014/05/que-es-api/) (te recomiendo que lo leas)
- [Introducción a ASP.NET Web API 2 (C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) (para implementar el punto anterior en un sitio ASP.NET)